# How to pass a Javascript array of any size to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, web-applications, parameters

I have an array in Javascript with many possible sizes. Is there any way for me to pass it to a PHP file for computation?

I would like to use something like a form in html

```
<form id="barfoo" action="foobar.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="foo">
  <input type="hidden" name="bar"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="bam">
</form>
```

Usually, these inputs are strings. Is there any way to have an array as input to pass? Like `fooarray=['abc', 'dbe', '3r']`, or `fooarray=['1','c','4','5']`. Before it is generated, I don't know the size of it. Is it possible to put it in a form and pass?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

use `JSON.stringify(array)` to encode your array in JavaScript, and then use `$arr=json_decode($_POST['jsondata']);` in PHP

Answer (score 2):

Encode the array into JSON and then insert it into one of the hiddens. This could be done in the forms `onsubmit` event.

```
<form id="barfoo" action="foobar.php" method="post" onsubmit="populate()">
<input type="hidden" id="foo" name="foo">
</form>

<script>
var  fooarray=['1','c','4','5'];

function populate()
{
    document.getElementById("foo").value = JSON.stringify(fooarray);
}
</script>
```

PHP has native support for decoding JSON using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$fooArray = json_decode($_POST['foo']);
print_r($fooArray);
```

Comment: may be send them as ajax ?